# Get store e-mail in phtml file

Tags: magento2, email, configuration

I want to retrieve `store-email` in **phtml** file so far i've fetched store data information like this but there's no info about **e-mail address**:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeInformation = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Information');
$store = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Store');
$storeInfo = $storeInformation->getStoreInformationObject($store); 
$storeData = $storeInfo->getData();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tested and working

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        


echo $conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email');
```

Output **owner@example.com**

Comment: got this error Error filtering template: Invalid scope type '1'

Comment: @ShellSuite update the code

Comment: it prints nothing

Comment: @ShellSuite i tested this code there was mistake now working fine

Comment: thanks its working, is there a way to retieve like the sales e-mail and others store e-mail?

Comment: @ShellSuite just change `trans_email/ident_general/email` with `trans_email/ident_sales/email` you will get sale email

Comment: How can I get the "Customer Support" email address? I have already tried "{{config path="trans_email/ident_support/email"}}" but it is not working.

Comment: @ChintanKaneriya magento have limited access to config values check class **\Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables::__construct**