# How to get Email address in my phtml file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, header

I want to display email address stored in backend into my header part.
How can i get email address into my header.phtml file in magento2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> objectManager is not recommended so there a better way of implementing
>   it.

Add Below code in phtml file:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email');

echo $conf //print email address
```

More reference check [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192874/get-store-e-mail-in-phtml-file/192882)

Comment: i dont want to show customer's email address. I want to show stores email address which we store in stores information in admin panel

Comment: ok, check again the link I have to update.

Comment: Ok thanx, can you also help me to add social icons on header?

Comment: I am happy to working code so accept an answer more discus open tag.

Comment: Done. Please help me in adding social icons in header

Comment: next time please ask a new question because that is a good way. so add icon check this link to helpful https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/222778887-Add-social-links-to-a-static-block-or-page-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102670/discussion-between-nafisa-and-vishal-baraiya).

Comment: I think objectmanager should always be discouraged. This is NOT the best way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Use helper to get email address in phtml. You can do it by following way.

In phtml:

```
$helper = $this->helper('Vendorname\Modulename\Helper\Data');
$email = $helper->getEmails();
//pass storeId  in getEmails if you want to get email for specific store
```

In helper define any function, For example getEmails().

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
   public function getEmails($storeId = null) {
      return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
   }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As per magento2 object manager is bad practice, use ScopeConfigInterface to get backend stored email address. Pass section_id/group_id/field_id from system.xml to get config value.
Try below code and please let me know if got any issue.

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Email extends Template
{
protected $scopeConfig;
public function __construct(Template\Context $context, ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
{
  $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
  return parent::__construct($context);
}
   public function getEmails() {

   return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('path/of/config', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

 }
}
```